# Подключение файлов из другой системной директории php

Tags: php, linux

В каталоге

/home/username/folder/

Лежит файл test.php

В каталоге /var/www/site/

Находится index.php

Хочу подключить командой include '....test.php'

В test.php имеется 'echo 1'
При открытии сайта не выводится единичка. Как правильно подключать такие файлы? Может определённые права должны быть установлены?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
include "../home/username/folder/test.php";
```

или

```
include "/home/username/folder/test.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь что PHP может выходить за рамки своей директории (прописывается в php.ini как **open_basedir**). А также что файл существует и вы не ошиблись в имени. Проверить можно так

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

print_r(ini_get('open_basedir'));
print_r(file_exists("/home/username/folder/test.php"));
print_r(file_get_contents("/home/username/folder/test.php"));
require_once "/home/username/folder/test.php";
```

Результат в студию)